# How can we simulate daily return based on multi-factor model?

Tags: monte-carlo, factor-models, simulations, covariance-matrix, geometric-brownian

This is an interesting question for simulation. The question is a bit lengthy but I'm trying my best to make it super clear here.

Now I have some multi-factor model, say some US barra risk model from MSCI. I have the factor return, factor covariance, factor loadings and idiosyncratic risk. The question is that, how can we effectively simulate multi-day stock daily return from the factor model?

Here is my thought and steps:

Define: 
$f$ is number of factors 
$s$ is number of stocks 
$nsim$ is number of simulations 
$FR$ as factor return ($f$ x $1$) matrix from day $t_0$ 
$FC$ as factor covariance ($f$ x $f$) matrix from day $t_0$ 
$FL$ as factor loadings ($s$ x $f$) matrix from day $t_0$  
$SRISK$ as idiosyncratic risk ($s$ x $1$) matrix from day $t_0$

1. Generate a ($f$ x $nsim$) matrix from standard normal as $Z1$
2. Do cholesky decomposition for factor covariance, let $FC=A*A^T$
3. Then, the simulated factor return is $SRF = FR + A*Z1$, note that one need to handle the shape of factor return here. $SRF$ is with shape ($f$ x $nsim$)
4. So we need to multiply with factor loadings, that is $FL * SRF$, with shape ($s$ x $nsim$). This is the **effective contribution of return from factor piece**.
5. Generate another ($1$ x $nsim$) matrix from standard normal as $Z2$
6. **The effective contribution of return from idiosyncratic piece** is $SRISK * Z2$, with shape ($s$ x $nsim$).
7. Adding step 4 and 6 together would give us the simulated daily return, say $SR$, which is also shape as ($s$ x $nsim$), meaning $nsim$ simulation for $s$ stocks.

Now the problem is that output from step 7 is daily return, which should be larger than -1. But we don't have this guarantee. **Notice that there is a reason why people simulate stock price, because if you assume stock price follow geometric brownian motion**, then you would never get negative stock price, and further no daily return smaller than -1. I'm having trouble linking my simulated daily return with GBM. Having said that, let me share my thought and please correct me:

1. First and naive way is do rejection. When there is daily return smaller than -1, one need to re-do the simulation. This is not ideal and not matrix friendly.
2. Second way. Notice that log(1+x) ~= x, we can let $log(1+R) = SR$, which will give us $R = exp(SR) - 1$, where $R$ is the final daily return we want and prevent "bad" simulated return. However, I'm not sure how this is related with GBM model and more importantly whether this is a valid approach.

Comment: For those who don't familiar with multi-factor model. An super quick recap of how the model (regression) work: 

daily_return ~ beta_1*factor_loadings_1 + beta2*factor_loadings_2 + ... + beta_f*factor_loadings_f + idio_syncratic_return. 

The beta here is the factor return.

Comment: Factor loadings is the exposure that the stock has on certain factor. Just think of it as some input features to the regression. Y is daily_return, X is factor_loadings.

Comment: You could edit your post to include the information from the comments. That would be a more elegant solution than a post followed by some explanatory comments.